# Assertions about data in infrastructure code as unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have some Python tests I have written, but these are for making assertions about data in infrastructure code (AWS CloudFormation templates). I am using the Unittest framework.

I have code like this:

```python
class TestData(unittest.TestCase):

    def testConfigStackYaml(self):

        bad_list = []
        for stack in glob('*/config'):

            stack_name = os.path.dirname(stack)
            expected_file = "%s/config/%s.yaml" % (stack_name, stack_name)

            if not os.path.isfile(expected_file):
                bad_list.append(expected_file)

        assert not bad_list, "Expected config/<stack_name>.yaml files to exist: %s" % bad_list

    def testStacksetMk(self):

        bad_list = []
        for stack in glob('*/config'):

            stack_name = os.path.dirname(stack)
            expected_file = "%s/stackset.mk" % stack_name

            if not os.path.isfile(expected_file):
                bad_list.append(expected_file)

        assert not bad_list, "Expected stackset.mk file to exist: %s" % bad_list
```

These are just two of my test cases. I have plenty more.

As can be seen, there is a problem with this code. The for loop for each test case is repeated for each test case, resulting in code duplication and inefficient code.

I have done it this way, however, because I want each test case to yield a helpful, specific message about what is wrong.

Can anyone see a cleaner way to implement this, so that I have the best of both worlds: duplication refactored out, but I still get to have a separate test case for each logical test?

Comment: Title of the question doesn't convey your business requirement. Can you change it to something that describes what you are trying to do. How about `Assertions about data in infrastructure code as unit tests`

Comment: @bhathiya-perera ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting code.

---

**Criticism:**

> ```
> def testConfigStackYaml(self):
> ```

- Can we rename these functions to `snake_case` such as `test_config_stack_yaml` maybe.

> ```
> assert not bad_list, "Expected config/<stack_name>.yaml files to exist: %s" % bad_list
> ```

- You can access unit test asserts from `TestCas
- How:

  - `self.assertTrue(expr, msg=None)`
  - `self.assertFalse(expr, msg=None)`
- More information at: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue

> ```
> expected_file = "%s/config/%s.yaml" % (stack_name, stack_name)
> ```

- I personally like using the new formatter. `%` is more unreadable compared to
  `"{stack_name}/config/{stack_name}".format(stack_name=stack_name)`
- We can also use `os.path.join` to join sections of a path. This makes our intention clear.

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     unittest.main()
> ```

- If you add this to the end of the file you can run these test files individually as a simple script.

---

**Creating a custom assert**

- I recommend creating a memeber function named `assert_config_exists`.
- Parameters: `path_format`, `message_format`

````
def assert_config_exists(self, path_format: str, message_format: str):
    bad_list = []
    for stack in glob('*/config'):

        stack_name = os.path.dirname(stack)
        expected_file = path_format.format(stack_name=stack_name)

        if not os.path.isfile(expected_file):
            bad_list.append(expected_file)

    self.assertFalse(bad_list, message_format.format(bad_list=bad_list))
```
````

Comment: Thank you, note that camelCase is used for consistency with the Unittest framework itself, whose methods are named setUp, tearDown etc.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I see your point https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html The examples in there use snake_case all the same. I guess the Python community really really likes snake_case. :)

Comment: This is very helpful. I could be missing something, but does that custom member function somehow allow me to address the duplication issue?

Comment: Oh...my bad. I chose these examples badly. There are other examples I have that couldn't be refactored so easily this way. Ok, this is correct.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Might it be worth adding those other examples as an edit to your post? Or would you rather create a different question entirely?

Comment: @AMC It's not allowed to change the question after getting answers. It will invalidate the answer/effort I made. Alex you can create a new question 